# Logging from serial is not real-time. How to make it not drift off?

Tags: python, arduino, delay

I'm getting a value of my moisture sensor over serial from Arduino to Raspberry PI. My Python script is supposed to log it. And it does, but the timing is getting delayed more and more exponentially. My guess (after 5 hours of Google) is that the problem is in the buffer somewhere and I am reading old data and "catching up". How do I adjust my code to get the latest serial info from my Arduino? Please keep in mind that I am a BIG noob and if you can explain as simple as possible. I've been up all night figuring it out but it's just that I know so very little about programming. Also adding the graph, there you can see the drift-off, I put the sensor out of water and put it in when I saw the graph drop.

[image]

Arduino code:

```cpp
/*
Chirp - arduino example

Connection 
Chirp pin 1 - no connection
Chirp pin 2 - Arduino VCC
Chirp pin 3 - Arduino A5
Chirp pin 4 - Arduino A4
Chirp pin 5 - Arduino pin 2
Chirp pin 6 - Arduino GND
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#define RELAY1  7

void writeI2CRegister8bit(int addr, int value) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(value);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

unsigned int readI2CRegister16bit(int addr, int reg) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(reg);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(1100);
  Wire.requestFrom(addr, 2);
  unsigned int t = Wire.read() << 8;
  t = t | Wire.read();
  return t;
}

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW); //Reset the Chirp
  delay(1); //maybe allow some time for chirp to reset
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH); //Go out from reset
  writeI2CRegister8bit(0x20, 3); //send something on the I2C bus
  delay(1000); //allow chirp to boot
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(readI2CRegister16bit(0x20, 0)); //read capacitance register
  //writeI2CRegister8bit(0x20, 3); //request light measurement 
  //delay(9000);                   //this can take a while
  //Serial.print(", ");
  //Serial.println(readI2CRegister16bit(0x20, 4)); //read light register
  if (readI2CRegister16bit(0x20, 0) < 420){
  //Serial.println ("watering"); 
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}
else{
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
  //Serial.println ("moist");
  delay(2000);
}
}
```

Python code:

```py
import serial
import time
import csv
import os
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout, Figure

os.chdir('/home/pi/csvdata')

username = '------------'
api_key = '------------'
stream_token = '------------'
py.sign_in(username, api_key)


trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    stream=dict(
        token=stream_token,
        maxpoints=200000000000
    )
)

layout = Layout(
    title='------------'
)

fig = Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout)

print py.plot(fig, filename='------------')

stream = py.Stream(stream_token)
stream.open()






def mainloop():
    name=time.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
    f=open(name+'.csv', 'wt')
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600,timeout=1)

    for t in range(500):
        #time.sleep(5)
        kk=ser.readline()
        kk2=kk.split('\r',1)
        s=kk2[0]
        text=time.strftime('%X %x'),s
        streamtext=({'x': time.strftime('%X %x'), 'y': kk})
        writer.writerow (text)
        stream.write (streamtext)
        f.flush()
        print (text)
        time.sleep(5);
        ser.flush()
        #ser.flushInput()
        #ser.flushOutput()

    if t  == 499:
        print ("why")
        f.close()
        ser.close()
        mainloop()
    else:
        time.sleep(5);

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please insert your code

Comment: Just had a quick look at your code. You seem to wait for a long time (5 seconds) in your Python script. I don't think you need that, `ser.readline()` will block until it receives new data anyway. Have you tried removing `time.sleep(5)`?

Comment: Hi Sven, I tried and  I get only blanks ' '.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your code from the Arduino and Python, so here is an example that demonstrates what you want to do. copy the relevant parts into your code.

#### Arduino:

```c
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int moisture_value = random(300);
  // millis() is the time in milliseconds since the arduino started running
  Serial.println(String(millis()) + ":" + String(moisture_value)); // We send two pieces of data, i.e. time since arduino started and the sensor value
  delay(1000);
}
```

#### Python:

```py
import serial
import datetime


# Converts to an integer if it is an integer, or it returns it as a string
def try_parse_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
time_start = datetime.datetime.now()  # The time that we started receiving data

while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip('\n').strip('\r')  # remove newline and carriage return characters
    [time, moisture_value] = data.split(':')
    print("Received: '{}'".format(data))
    time_received = time_start + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=try_parse_int(time))  # Add delta time to start time
    print("Moisture value: {} at {}".format(try_parse_int(moisture_value), time_received))
```

This works by sending the time since the Arduino started along with the sensor reading. If we add this to the know starting time in Python, then  we know the time that the reading was taken. Even if the sending is delayed for some reason, it doesn't matter.

#### Example output:

```
Received: '0:116'
Moisture value: 116 at 2017-03-15 11:26:43.024711
Received: '1000:4'
Moisture value: 4 at 2017-03-15 11:26:44.024711
Received: '2000:128'
Moisture value: 128 at 2017-03-15 11:26:45.024711
Received: '3001:123'
Moisture value: 123 at 2017-03-15 11:26:46.025711
```

#### Time formatting:

You can also format the time in a way that you prefer;

```py
time_received = time_start + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=try_parse_int(time))  # Add delta time to start time
time_formatted = '{0:%H}:{0:%M}:{0:%S} on {0:%d}/{0:%m}/{0:%y}'.format(time_received)
print("Moisture value: {} at {}".format(try_parse_int(moisture_value), time_formatted))
```

Output:

```
Moisture value: 46 at 11:42:10 on 15/03/17
Received: '117050:174'
Moisture value: 174 at 11:42:11 on 15/03/17
Received: '118050:298'
```

Comment: This is a great post, but it answers a different question than *"How do I adjust my code to get the latest serial info from my arduino?"*.